# Functional-analysis, isometrical isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $\ell^1:=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}\colon \|f\|_1:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)|<\infty\}$ provided with $\|\cdot\|_1$.
>   Show, that $S: \ell^1\to c_0'$ is an isometrical isomorphism.

First of all I am not sure on what $S$ is supposed to be, since there is missing a definition. Also $l^1\stackrel{?}{=}\ell^1$ might be a typo aswell.
We defined $S_f: c_0\to\mathbb{C}$ by $S_f(g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)f(n)$.
But what is $S$?
Also $c_0'$ notes the dual space of $c_0$.

Or do I have to define it myself, since I have to find a isomorphism of vectorspaces, which is an isometric?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: S sends f to $S_f$

Comment: Can you give me more insight on how to tackle this problem? I am stuck.

Comment: I just proved this in your other post: the proof that $\|f \|_1 = \|S_f\|_{\text{op}}$ is exactly what it means to for $\ell^1$ and $c_0'$ to be isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: @User8128: Except for the part about showing that $S$ is surjective.

Comment: Why is it enough to show, that $S$ is surjective? And how can I do this, since. You said, that $S:\ell^1\to c_0$, with $S(f)=S_f$, but $S_f$ is a function and not a complex number?

Comment: @Cornman: No, $S:\ell^1\to c_0'$, and $S_f$ is a function, as it must be to be an element of $c_0'$.  It is enough to show that $S$ satisfies all of the properties in the definition of isometric isomorphism.  One of those properties is being surjective.  The others are covered in your other question it appears.

Comment: Do you mind extending this comment into an answer, or give a hint on how I can show that $S$ is surjective? I have to show that for every $g\in c_0'$ we have an $f\in\ell^1$ sucht that $S(f)=g$. Now $g\in c_0'$, hence $g:c_0\to\mathbb{C}$ is linear and continuous.

Comment: I won't answer but I'll answer your comment with a suggestion and be done: Yes that's what you have to show.  If $h$ is the element of $c_0$ such that $h(n) =1$ and $h(m)=0$ for all $m\neq n$, define $f(n) = g(h)$.  This defines an $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb C$.  Perhaps you can show that $f\in \ell^1$ and $g=S_f$.

Comment: Thank you. I try to take it from here.